# How to compare elements of list with each other with java 8 stream

Tags: java, list, java-8, filtering, java-stream

I have a List with random words and I want to filter all the words with same length or with same first letter?

How to check the element with each other in a list with java 8 streams?

Comment: `myList.stream()
                .filter(x -> x.startsWith("xxx") || x -> x.length() == SIZE)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: there is **a lot of** questions like "filtering a stream by condition", I am sure it's a duplicate. What's the problem you have encountered with? What have you tried?

Comment: "Same length" as what? "Same first letter" as what? Each other? If list is `"Can", "You", "Take", "Care"`, there are two words of length 3, and two words of length 4. How do you *filter* that by "words with same length"? Note that *filtering* and *grouping* are entirely different operations.

Answer (score 4):

To retrieve a list of strings that start with a particular letter/word:

```
List<String> resultSet = myList.stream()
                .filter(x -> x.startsWith("a"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To maintain a record of all strings that have the same length, then consider using a `groupingBy` collector.

```
 Map<Integer, List<String>> resultSet = myList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length));
```

if you know exactly the length of the strings you're interested in then you can do:

```
List<String> resultSet = myList.stream()
                .filter(x -> x.length() == 5)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also, you can combine the two filter operations to maintain a list of strings that either have specific length or a start with a specific word/letter:

```
List<String> resultSet = myList.stream()
                               .filter(x -> x.startsWith("a") ||
                                         x.length() == 5)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```